# Unable to read Properties from .properties file in Grails App

Tags: grails

I have a Property file under **grails-app/conf** with name config.properties

In my Config.groovy, I have properties as this

**dfs.replication = '1'**

In my Config.groovy, i have the following code

```
grails.config.locations = ["classpath:config.properties",
                           "classpath:config-${stage}.properties",
                          // "file:${configLocation}",
                           "${catalina.base}/../config/config.properties"
]
```

When I try to read 
**grailsApplication.config.dfs.replication**

I get below Error

**Method threw 'groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException' exception.**

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I had missed out on Autowiring grailsApplication in my Groovy File.

After Autowiring grailsApplication, it worked for me.

Thanks
Vinod